# WPF Button within a frame in a page navigates to change the parent page

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, frame, parent

I am very new to WPF but really enjoying it at the moment. I have a question about page navigation that I am trying to implement.

I have the MainWindow.xaml which has a frame inside it.
On startup, the frame loads page 1.
Page 1 has a button in it.
If you click on the button, page two appears inside the frame.
However, I don't want this. When the user clicks on the button in page 1, I want the whole page(MainWindow.xaml) to navigate to page 2. So I need the actual parent page itself to change.

I am using the following code on the button's Click event. I just don't know how to refer to the parent page.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new PageTwoReplacesMainPage());
        }
```

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.
I hope this makes sense and any help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

The MainWindow.xaml code is...

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfParentNavigation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfParentNavigation"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" MinHeight="500" MinWidth="700" Background="Beige">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Frame x:Name="myMainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Height="400" Width="600" Margin="0,50,0,0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Page1.xaml is...

```
<Page x:Class="TestWpfParentNavigation.PageOneWithButton"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfParentNavigation"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="PageOneWithButton" Background="Bisque">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Go to the second page" Height="30" Width="150" Click="Button_Click" Margin="10,10,140,160" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Page2.xaml is...

```
<Page x:Class="TestWpfParentNavigation.PageTwoReplacesMainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWpfParentNavigation"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="PageTwoReplacesMainPage" Background="Aqua">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Please provide the XAML for your UI.

Comment: MainWindow is not a page, it's a window. What do you mean when you say you want the 'whole page' to navigate?

Comment: Did you tried to make frame in grid Instead of stackpanel? It should fit whole window then.

Comment: I dont want the second page to appear in the frame. I want the whole of the MainWindow to display the second page.

Comment: I am trying to implement a masterpage type of layout. I have pages which will have common controls so I wanted to allocate a portion of the screen to the common controls and the rest to the different page content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. I misunderstood the way a Window is supposed to work.

To solve my problem, I did the following:

In the MainWindow.xaml, I created a frame which covered the whole window.
Then I loaded a page into the frame. This page had a second frame in it.
In the The second frame, I load the second page which has the button.
When I click on the button, I can now access the very first frame and navigate to the page that I wanted. This means I can utlise my masterpage concept now.

Thank you all for trying to help. You gave me the clues to understand my problem and answer it. Kind regards. I hope this answer makes sense and helps anyone else.